# Selenium Grid connection refusal

Tags: java, ios, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a suite of iOS tests that I'm trying to run on real devices (iOS 12). I'm using a combination of appium (1.9.2-beta3) and docker's selenium/hub (3.141.5), running on bamboo. 
All appears to be correctly set up, but when I kick off the tests, the connection is refused. EDIT: The WebDriver Agent launches the app no problem, but that's when it just stops.

I've attached a log from the selenium node here. I haven't done any troubleshooting in this area before, so this may be too vague, but can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or how to get them talking to each other?

EDIT: the docker-coompose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4450:4444"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - engine.labels.stage == qa
    environment:
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=60000
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=90000
      - GRID_MAX_SESSION=50
      - GRID_CLEAN_UP_CYCLE=60000
      - GRID_UNREGISTER_IF_STILL_DOWN_AFTER=180000
      - GRID_NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT=120000
    labels:
      com.docker.ucp.access.label: "qa-label"
```

```
    018-11-08 16:31:16,934 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/selenium-hub.conf" during parsing
2018-11-08 16:31:16,948 INFO supervisord started with pid 8
2018-11-08 16:31:17,950 INFO spawned: 'selenium-hub' with pid 11
Starting Selenium Hub with configuration:
2018-11-08 16:31:17,964 INFO success: selenium-hub entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
{
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 4444,
  "role": "hub",
  "maxSession": 50,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": 120000,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "jettyMaxThreads": -1,
  "cleanUpCycle": 60000,
  "browserTimeout": 60000,
  "timeout": 90000,
  "debug": false
}
16:31:19.138 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.5, revision: d54ebd709a
16:31:19.447 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
2018-11-08 16:31:20.149:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1993ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
16:31:20.508 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
16:31:20.509 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://IP:4444/grid/register/
16:31:20.509 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://IP:4444/wd/hub
16:32:32.199 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://IP:4741
16:32:38.715 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {app: /Users/user/appium/mobil..., automationName: XCUITEST, browserName: Gandalf iPad, deviceName: Gandalf iPad, platform: MAC, platformName: ios, platformVersion: 12.0, udid: 48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc9..., wdaLocalPort: 8108, xcodeOrgId: 66Y9F4A25A, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}
16:32:38.718 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=011ef51c-2b69-48b3-83c2-f12503f0165f, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=Gandalf iPad, maxInstances=1, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
16:33:24.289 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {app: /Users/user/appium/mobil..., automationName: XCUITEST, browserName: Gandalf iPad, deviceName: Gandalf iPad, platform: MAC, platformName: ios, platformVersion: 12.0, udid: 48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc9..., wdaLocalPort: 8108, xcodeOrgId: 66Y9F4A25A, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}
16:33:24.291 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=011ef51c-2b69-48b3-83c2-f12503f0165f, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=Gandalf iPad, maxInstances=1, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
2018-11-08 16:33:49.346:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp2048834776-29: /wd/hub/session java.io.IOException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: No capabilities found in request: {"capabilities": {"desiredCapabilities": {"app":"/Users/user/appium/mobilev2app/OFW TapQA Distro 2018-10-22 Build83/OFW TapQA Distro.ipa","platformVersion":"12.0","xcodeOrgId":"66Y9F4A25A","automationName":"XCUITEST","browserName":"Gandalf iPad","udid":"48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc92061021b5f15c","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"Gandalf iPad","platform":"MAC","xcodeSigningId":"iPhone Developer","wdaLocalPort":8108},"requiredCapabilities": {}}}
16:33:51.367 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {app: /Users/user/appium/mobil..., automationName: XCUITEST, browserName: Gandalf iPad, deviceName: Gandalf iPad, platform: MAC, platformName: ios, platformVersion: 12.0, udid: 48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc9..., wdaLocalPort: 8108, xcodeOrgId: 66Y9F4A25A, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}
16:33:51.368 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=011ef51c-2b69-48b3-83c2-f12503f0165f, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=Gandalf iPad, maxInstances=1, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
16:34:13.933 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {app: /Users/user/appium/mobil..., automationName: XCUITEST, browserName: Gandalf iPad, deviceName: Gandalf iPad, platform: MAC, platformName: ios, platformVersion: 12.0, udid: 48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc9..., wdaLocalPort: 8108, xcodeOrgId: 66Y9F4A25A, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}
16:34:13.933 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=011ef51c-2b69-48b3-83c2-f12503f0165f, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=Gandalf iPad, maxInstances=1, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
2018-11-08 16:34:36.861:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp2048834776-42: /wd/hub/session java.io.IOException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: No capabilities found in request: {"capabilities": {"desiredCapabilities": {"app":"/Users/user/appium/mobilev2app/OFW TapQA Distro 2018-10-22 Build83/OFW TapQA Distro.ipa","platformVersion":"12.0","xcodeOrgId":"66Y9F4A25A","automationName":"XCUITEST","browserName":"Gandalf iPad","udid":"48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc92061021b5f15c","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"Gandalf iPad","platform":"MAC","xcodeSigningId":"iPhone Developer","wdaLocalPort":8108},"requiredCapabilities": {}}}
16:34:38.877 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {app: /Users/user/appium/mobil..., automationName: XCUITEST, browserName: Gandalf iPad, deviceName: Gandalf iPad, platform: MAC, platformName: ios, platformVersion: 12.0, udid: 48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc9..., wdaLocalPort: 8108, xcodeOrgId: 66Y9F4A25A, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}
16:34:38.878 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=011ef51c-2b69-48b3-83c2-f12503f0165f, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=Gandalf iPad, maxInstances=1, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
16:35:01.649 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {app: /Users/user/appium/mobil..., automationName: XCUITEST, browserName: Gandalf iPad, deviceName: Gandalf iPad, platform: MAC, platformName: ios, platformVersion: 12.0, udid: 48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc9..., wdaLocalPort: 8108, xcodeOrgId: 66Y9F4A25A, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}
16:35:01.650 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=011ef51c-2b69-48b3-83c2-f12503f0165f, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=Gandalf iPad, maxInstances=1, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
2018-11-08 16:35:23.847:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp2048834776-14: /wd/hub/session java.io.IOException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: No capabilities found in request: {"capabilities": {"desiredCapabilities": {"app":"/Users/user/appium/mobilev2app/OFW TapQA Distro 2018-10-22 Build83/OFW TapQA Distro.ipa","platformVersion":"12.0","xcodeOrgId":"66Y9F4A25A","automationName":"XCUITEST","browserName":"Gandalf iPad","udid":"48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc92061021b5f15c","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"Gandalf iPad","platform":"MAC","xcodeSigningId":"iPhone Developer","wdaLocalPort":8108},"requiredCapabilities": {}}}
16:35:25.859 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {app: /Users/user/appium/mobil..., automationName: XCUITEST, browserName: Gandalf iPad, deviceName: Gandalf iPad, platform: MAC, platformName: ios, platformVersion: 12.0, udid: 48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc9..., wdaLocalPort: 8108, xcodeOrgId: 66Y9F4A25A, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}
16:35:25.860 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=011ef51c-2b69-48b3-83c2-f12503f0165f, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=Gandalf iPad, maxInstances=1, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
16:35:43.028 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Failed to connect to /<IPAddress>:4741
org.openqa.grid.internal.exception.NewSessionException: Error forwarding the request Failed to connect to /<IPAddress>:4741
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.forwardNewSessionRequestAndUpdateRegistry(RequestHandler.java:94)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:114)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:85)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /<IPAddress>:4741
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.TestSession.sendRequestToNode(TestSession.java:422)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.TestSession.forward(TestSession.java:229)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.forwardNewSessionRequestAndUpdateRegistry(RequestHandler.java:91)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
    ... 56 more
16:35:43.064 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {app: /Users/user/appium/mobil..., automationName: XCUITEST, browserName: Gandalf iPad, deviceName: Gandalf iPad, platform: MAC, platformName: ios, platformVersion: 12.0, udid: 48527f94911a9d6cd0cf1c98fc9..., wdaLocalPort: 8108, xcodeOrgId: 66Y9F4A25A, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer}
16:35:43.065 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=011ef51c-2b69-48b3-83c2-f12503f0165f, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=Gandalf iPad, maxInstances=1, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
16:35:43.078 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Failed to connect to /<IPAddress>:4741
org.openqa.grid.internal.exception.NewSessionException: Error forwarding the request Failed to connect to /<IPAddress>:4741
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.forwardNewSessionRequestAndUpdateRegistry(RequestHandler.java:94)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:114)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:85)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /<IPAddress>:4741
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.TestSession.sendRequestToNode(TestSession.java:422)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.TestSession.forward(TestSession.java:229)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.forwardNewSessionRequestAndUpdateRegistry(RequestHandler.java:91)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: Could you include your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @bluescores I've edited the question to include the yml file.

Comment: @bluescores Any insight? Thanks!